# Вимикати чи Виключати?

Tags: вживання-слів

**Вимикати** - це суто українське слово, яке є відповідником російського "виключати". Але є винятки, коли в українській мові вживається **"виключати"**.

**Вимикати, вимкнути.** Припиняти дію чого-небудь, перериваючи зв’язок із загальною системою: вимикати, вимкнути струм, вимикати телефон, вимкнути мотор, вимкнути опалення, вимкнути воду.

**Виключати, виключити.** В цьому значенні вживається зрідка – тільки стосовно машин: виключити мотор, виключити верстат.

Comment: В чому полягає ваше запитання? Ви ж самі зазначили, що ці два слова вживаються в різних випадках. Чи потрібно більше прикладів?

Comment: Podibne + anqlijsjke: [**вимикач**, **вмикач** or **перемикач**](/q/1426/585). Teg ne rozumiju zapytannja.

Comment: Вимикати чи виключати що? Наведіть будь ласка приклади речень, в яких ви не знаєте яке слово краще вжити. У різних контекстах вживаються різні слова, про що і написано у словниках. Який контекст цікавить саме вас?

Comment: Я зрозумів - ви намагаєтеся поділитися знаннями. В такому разі треба додати питання "вимикати чи виключати" із прикладами де є труднощі у використанні, а потім треба додати відповідь де ви **відповідаєте  на своє питання** і пояснюєте, як і чому у цих випадках треба використовувати одне слово замість іншого. Просто відповісти прямо у запитанні за правилами цього сайту - не можна.

Answer (score 2):

У цьому [джерелі](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine9-16.pdf) дуже гарно сформульовані випадки вживання вказаних Вами слів:

> Певні сумніви щодо вживання викликають слова *вмика́ти* — *включа́ти*, *вимика́ти* — *виключа́ти*. Кожна пара цих слів об’єднує близькі, але не тотожні значення.
>
> Так, слова *вмикати* і *включати* пов’язані із значенням «з’єднувати з джерелом енергії, уводити в дію». Наприклад: «Олександр побачив біля дошки механіка, який *вмикав* рубильники» (Панч); «Юрій *увімкнув* світло» (Собко); «Сергій Іванович підійшов до приймача, *включив*» (Головко).
>
> Інших значень слово *вмикати* не має, а слово *включати* вживається ще і в другому значенні — «уводити до складу, приєднувати до кого-, чого-небудь». Наприклад: «В міськкомі партії радо зустріли професора Драгу і одразу *включили* до лекторської групи» (Кучер).
>
> Слова *вимикати* — *виключати* відповідно збігаються в значенні «припиняти дію чого-небудь, переривати зв’язок із загальною системою»: «І взявся усунути обрив проводів, не *вимикаючи* струму» (Гончар); «Потім я *вимикаю* телефон, світло і віддаюся думам» (Яновський); «Машина чекає, — сказав він, — я навіть наказав не *виключати* мотор» (Смолич).
>
> Крім цього, слово *виключати* має ще такі значення: «усувати із складу чого-небудь, позбавлятися чогось; виводити із складу якоїсь організації, позбавляти права вчитися в навчальному закладі». Наприклад: «Я *виключив* зі свого лексикону займенники я, моє, мені, а почав уживати ми, наше, нам» (Коцюбинський); «Овсій Колода запропонував: Чого з ними панькатись? *Виключити* з колгоспу і все тут» (Кучер).
>
> Отже, слова *включати* — *виключати* мають ширше коло значень, ніж *вмикати* — *вимикати*, але в одному вони збігаються, а саме в значенні «уводити в дію» чи «припиняти дію».
>
> Уживанішими в українській мові щодо зв’язку з електричним струмом, радіо,
>   телефонною мережею є слова *вмикати* — *вимикати*. Тому й пристрої, які використовуються для з’єднання або роз’єднання з такою системою, називаються *вмикач* і *вимикач*.
>
> Слова *включати* — *виключати* більше пов’язуються з уведенням в дію мотора,
>   механізму, машини.

СУМ також дає пояснення:

> [**ВИКЛЮЧА́ТИ**](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=9089&page=321), а́ю, а́єш, недок., ВИ́КЛЮЧИТИ, чу, чиш, док.
>
> 1. Усувати зі складу чого-небудь, позбавлятися чогось. Щодо щастя свого, задоволення, то, ведучи розмову про них, я виключив зі свого лексикону займенники “я”, “моє”, “мені”, а почав уживати “ми”, “наше”, “нам”... (М. Коцюбинський); Правильне поєднання механізованих і хімічних заходів боротьби з бур'янами дає змогу повністю виключити ручну працю у догляді за посівами кукурудзи (із журн.); // Виводити зі складу якоїсь організації, колективу, позбавляти права вчитися в навчальному закладі. Тепер губернатор напевне вижене з служби, а директор виключить Дорю [з гімназії] (М. Коцюбинський); Тато ходив як хмара: Федька виключили з духовної семінарії (А. Дімаров); Член виробничого кооперативу, якого виключили з кооперативу, має право на одержання паю та інших виплат, установлених статутом кооперативу (з мови документів).
> 2. Робити неможливим що-небудь, не допускати наявності чогось за даних умов. Тисячі несподіванок у цій дивовижній трагікомедії виключали свідомість (Іван Ле); Людина нічого не повинна боятися. Вона може усвідомлювати ризик і виключати його (з наук.-попул. літ.).
> 3. Вимикати (прилади, механізми). Виходячи з дому, не забувайте виключати газ! (з газ.).
>
> ---
>
> ВИМИ́КУВАТИ, ую, уєш, недок., [**ВИ́МИКАТИ**](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=210516&page=332), аю, аєш, док., що, діал. Виривати. Іде баба на другий день на поле і починає вимикувати посіяний чортом бур'ян (з казки); – Раз якось уже й зацвів був [горох], та як ударив град, то стовк його дочиста. Люди вимикали, а я лишив (А. Крушельницький).
>
> ---
>
> [**ВИМИКА́ТИ**](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=9582&page=332), а́ю, а́єш, недок., ВИ́МКНУТИ, ну, неш, док., що. Припиняти дію чого-небудь, перериваючи зв'язок із загальною системою. Потім я вимикаю .. телефон, світло над головою і віддаюся думкам (Ю. Яновський); – Я взявся усунути обрив [проводів], не вимикаючи струму (О. Гончар); // Припиняти дію якого-небудь приладу, електричного механізму. Потужний прожектор, закріплений на грудях скафандра, давав сліпуче біле проміння. Галя кілька разів вмикала і вимикала його, знайшовши кнопку керування (В. Владко); Дорога в ущелині круто спадала вниз, шофер вів по ній машину, вимкнувши мотор (В. Кучер); // перен. Припиняти роботу, блокувати дію біологічного механізму. Ми поки що навчилися вимикати одиничні гени, на цьому ґрунтуються наші надії на лікування важких спадкових хвороб (з газ.).

Підсумовуючи все вище зазначене, можна зробити висновок, що *виключати* охоплює більш ширший діапазон значень, а *вимикати* — припиняти дію чого-небудь, перериваючи зв'язок із загальною системою, а також вимикати що-небудь з городу.